# .on() doesn't work properly with dynamic content

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple js script which gets backgrounds of the following elements:

```html
    <ul class="vk_image_grid">
      <li style="background-image: url(https://name.com/image1.jpg)" class="block">
      </li>
      <li style="background-image: url(https://name.com/image2.jpg)" class="block">
      </li>
      <li style="background-image: url(https://name.com/image3.jpg)" class="block">
      </li>
     </ul>
<script>
 $("ul li").on( "click", function() {
  var bg = $(this).css('background-image');
  alert(bg);
</script>
```

It works perfectly with the first two `li` which are generated by php. But it doesn't show the background of the third `li` which is generateed by another jQuery script. How can I fix the issue?

Comment: Have you searched how to bind an event handler to dynamic element? Doesn't seem so.

Comment: `$("body").on( "click", "ul li",function(){ //...`

Comment: `on()` has 2 signatures. Pay close attention to the delegation target signature. Note that the main selector must exist and you add a target argument for delegating

Comment: @chiliNUT, many thanks, it works now!

Comment: lol that the dupe is a dupe of another question

Answer (score -3):

The third li element seems to be generated after the `$("ul li")` has been run. Therefore the event handler won't be attached to the third li element.

Either you make sure the li is generated before you iterate the li's to attach the event handler or you add the event handler in the method where you generate the new li element.

To help you more precisely you need to provide more details of your code.

Comment: Bad answer. Should be a comment

Comment: No need for more detail...event delegation handles both scenarios. Downvotes are for missing the obvious and more common delegation approach